# Using a function that uses argv[] and argc in parameters to pass to pthread_create()

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm working on a program dealing with threads. I wrote the first function using argv[] like:

```
send_data = atoi(argv[1]);
```

I know that pthread_create needs to accept a parameter for a function that is a void* type and returns a void* type.

Is there anyway around the problem of using argv in a function to later pass it through pthread_create, or should I try to implement the function a different way?

Comment: If `argv[1]` is a `char*`, then simply cast it to `void*` before passing to `pthread_create`.

Comment: @DyZ: You don't need to cast the pointer to a void pointer; C will do that automatically.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fair enough. But it does not hurt, either.

Comment: Can the thread function not just read the command-line parameters itself?  Why do you need to signal it in the pthread_create() user-argument?